# My android app crashes when launching from gmail

Tags: android, crash, gmail, file-extension

I have an app that accosiates certain filendings. This works fine when browsing android built in file browser and clicking on an app but when launching the app through gmail app (send a file to email and then use download->open with application) then getIntent().getExtras() is null. I use extras to get the name of the file. How do i fix this? :(

Comment: please remove your question before you can get more minus..lol

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is much you can do but handling that it can be null.

Comment: I actually solved the problem :)                  
Gmail doesnt send extras but you can apperently use
String path = getIntent().getDataString().substring(7);
to get absolute path of file. Use ".substring(7)" to cut of "file://" :)